# BarButtonItem's Title Not Updating

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use this code throughout my project to update the title of my UIBarButtonItem.

In this particular class, I have an NSFetchedResultsController which I want to to get the count for to set as the button's title.

I am calling this code in ViwDidLoad but it seems as though it is being called before the fetch, therefore the count is always 0.  I tried putting it at the end of the Fetch delegate method, but that didn't help either.  Any ideas?  When I NSLog the count in the fetch delegate method, it is correct.

```
self.myBarButton.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i count", [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]];
```

viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        self.managedObjectContext = [(TestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSSet *filteredFromSession=[selectedSession.property filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == %@",name]];
    if ([filteredFromSession count] > 0)
    {
        self.exercise = [filteredExercisesFromSession anyObject];
    }
    self.setLabel.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i sets", [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]];
}
```

Comment: Is `setLabel` a UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry about the confusing name.

Comment: Can you add the rest of your `viewDidLoad` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probable that at the time you do this,

```
self.setLabel.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i sets", [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]];
```

`fetchedResultsController` is `nil`.

If you've a getter method defined for `fetchedResultsController` and have declared it as a property, I suggest you do the fetch before your line above,

```
NSError * error;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // Error
}
```

Basically ensure that the fetch is completed prior to setting the title. Once you do this, you might want to remove the fetch from the place you're doing right now.

Comment: Right now, I am using a NSFetchedResultsController though, not a regular FetechRequest

Comment: Yeah I haven't mentioned a fetch request. I am talking about an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: But the NSFetchedResultsController has its own method `(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController`.  You want me to move that into viewDidLoad instead?

Comment: What happens when you add the code I suggested above the `self.setLabel.title = ...` line?

Comment: I added this to viewDidLoad, but same problem.  `    NSError * error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        self.setLabel.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i sets", [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]];
`

Comment: @Jon Where do you perform your fetch? And do not include the `self.setLabel.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i sets", [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]];` inside the if clause. That is the failure condition.

Comment: Thanks I removed it from the if clause and it works now Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked "self.myBarButton" to make sure it's not nil at the time you're setting the title? (Like you forgot to set the outlet properly, etc)?

Comment: No that works, cause if I set it with a static text like `self.myBarButton.title = @"text";` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How you are accessing bar button item? how about accessing like this.

```
BarButtonItem * item = [self.navigationItem rightBarButtonItem];
[itme setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i count", [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]]
```

Comment: I'm using a toolbar, not a navbar, and the code I have works fine for setting a title.  The problem I think is that the fetch results is not fetching until after viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Jon Try setting title after fetching finished. Like you can use NSNOtification or delegate protocol to update the title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.setLabel.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d sets", [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]];
```

in place of

```
self.setLabel.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d sets", [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]];
```